# C: Convert string to unsigned long long Error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtoull

I'm simply trying to convert a `String` (readed from a line in a file) in a `long long` variable. My problem is that i get Segmentation Fault, and I don't know why... Here's the code: ***(I put a comment on the error on the "3° Call" function)***

```
#define CAPACITY (unsigned long long) 11
#define INTEGERS_PATH // the path to the file I wish to read

typedef struct {
    void** array;
    unsigned long long el_num;
    unsigned long long array_capacity;
    int (*compare)(void*,void*);
} GenericArray;

// used for compare elements
struct record{
    char* string_field; // used in case the GenericArray is made of strings items
    long long integer_field; // used in case the GenericArray is made of long long items
};

// END OF STRUCTS ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// BEGIN OF FUNCTIONS -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    test_with_comparison_function(compare_record_int_field);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

// Compare function passed to generic_array_create() for create the GenericArray
static int compare_record_int_field(void* r1_p,void* r2_p){
    if(r1_p == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"compare_record_int_field: the first parameter is a null pointer");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(r2_p == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"compare_record_int_field: the second parameter is a null pointer");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct record *rec1_p = (struct record*)r1_p;
    struct record *rec2_p = (struct record*)r2_p;

    if(rec1_p->integer_field < rec2_p->integer_field){
        return(1);
    }
    return(0);
}

// 1° Call
static void test_with_comparison_function(int (*compare)(void*, void*)) {
    GenericArray* array = generic_array_create(compare);
    load_array(array);
    print_array(array); // it prints the array
    free_array(array); // it frees the memory alocated by the array
}

// 2° Call
GenericArray *generic_array_create(int (*compare)(void*,void*)){
    GenericArray *array = malloc(sizeof(GenericArray));
    if(array == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "generic_array_create: unable to allocate memory for the generic array");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    array->array = malloc(CAPACITY * sizeof(void*));
    array->el_num = 0;
    array->array_capacity = CAPACITY;
    array->compare = compare;

    return(array);
}

// 3° Call
static void load_array(GenericArray* array){
    clock_t start = clock(); // for timing

    printf("\nLoading data from file...\n");

    FILE * dataset_p = fopen(INTEGERS_PATH, "r");
    if(dataset_p == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"main: unable to open the file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *read_line_p;
    char buffer[1024];
    int buf_size = 1024;

    while(fgets(buffer, buf_size, dataset_p) != NULL){
        read_line_p = malloc((strlen(buffer) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(read_line_p, buffer);
        char *string_field_in_read_line_p = strtok(read_line_p, "\n");
        char *integer_field_in_read_line_p = strtok(NULL, "\n");

        char *string_field_1 = malloc((strlen(string_field_in_read_line_p) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        char *string_field_2 = malloc((strlen(string_field_in_read_line_p) + 1) * sizeof(char));

        strcpy(string_field_1,string_field_in_read_line_p);
        strcpy(string_field_2,string_field_in_read_line_p);

        /* Here begins errors (SEGMENTATION FAULT) */
        int integer_field = atoi(integer_field_in_read_line_p); 
        long long integer_field = strtoll(integer_field_in_read_line_p, (char **) NULL, 10);

        struct record *record_p = malloc(sizeof(struct record));
        record_p->string_field = string_field_1;
        record_p->integer_field = integer_field;

        generic_array_add(array, (void*) record_p);

        free(read_line_p); 
    }

    fclose(dataset_p);
    printf("\nData loaded\n");
}
```

Here's the file which I want to read, it's a simple `.txt` file:

```
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
2
1
10
```

Comment: Check if `integer_field_in_read_line_p` is `NULL`. [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) may return `NULL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is these three lines:

```
while(fgets(buffer, buf_size, dataset_p) != NULL){
    // ...
    char *string_field_in_read_line_p = strtok(read_line_p, "\n");
    char *integer_field_in_read_line_p = strtok(NULL, "\n");
```

The [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) function reads *one* line, and leaves the newline `'\n'` at the end of that. That means there's only *one* `'\n'` in the string you attempt to tokenize. So the second call to `strtok` should return `NULL`.

You don't check for that, and therefore any dereference of that `NULL` pointer (which happens in the conversion functions) will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and possible crashes.

Comment: You get exatcly the point! Your solution worked! I'm gonna mark your answer as the solution in 3 minutes! Thank you!